# Using the Cauchy integral formula show that $\oint_{ |z|=2} \dfrac { e^zdz}{(z-1)^2(z-3)}= -\dfrac 3 2je\pi$

Tags: integration, solution-verification, cauchy-integral-formula

> Using the Cauchy integral formula show that
> $$\oint_{ |z|=2} \dfrac { e^zdz}{(z-1)^2(z-3)}= -\frac 3 2je\pi.$$

My work is in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b5MT.jpg). The answer is $-\frac 3 2je\pi$. I used the singularities and since $3$ wasn't included in the contour $|z|=2$, I omitted it. I don't know why I am getting a different answer.

I used partial fractions and had
$$ \dfrac a{z-1} + \dfrac b{z+1}$$ I took the limit
$$\lim_{ z \to 1} \dfrac {e^z}{z+1} = \dfrac e 2$$
and for $b$, I did
$$\lim_{ z \to -1} \dfrac { e^z }{ z-1} = -\dfrac 1 {2e}$$
My $f(z)$ became
$$\dfrac e{2(z-1)} - \dfrac 1{2e(z+1)}$$
I applied the Cauchy integral formula and I got
$$\dfrac e2(2j\pi) - \dfrac 1{2e}(2j\pi)
$$ but I need
$$-\frac 3 2je\pi$$

Comment: Please do just type it out, rather than using off-site links...

Comment: sorry, just joined the site

Comment: No problem. Typed-out things are more stable in the longer term, of course, not to mention more readable. :)

Comment: thank you and user577 for editing

Comment: @keinekinder See the MathJax tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @keinekinder $(z-1)^2 \neq (z+1)(z-1)$, you confused it with $z^2-1=(z+1)(z-1)$.

Comment: I made a mistake sorry @Gary I wanted to type the pseudo of op

Comment: @keinekinder Use the Cauchy formula $$
f^{(n)} (w) = \frac{{n!}}{{2\pi j}}\oint_{} {\frac{{f(z)}}{{(z - w)^{n + 1} }}dz} 
$$ with $w=1$, $n=1$ and $f(z) = \frac{{e^z }}{{z - 3}}$.

Comment: @Gary ah okay that makes alot more sense. Will try this, thank you!

Comment: Mathematicians usually prefer $i$ for $\sqrt {-1}$ while engineers usually prefer $j$ as they often use $i$ for electric current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your calculation using your approach but your partial fraction decomposition is not correct.

You have

$$\frac 1{(z-1)^2(z-3)}= -\frac 14 \frac 1{z - 1}-\frac 12 \frac 1{(z - 1)^2}+ \frac 14 \frac 1{z - 3}$$

Now, you can use Cauchy's formula directly omitting the on $|z|\leq 2$ holomorphic part belonging to $\frac 1{z-3}$:

\begin{eqnarray*}\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{(z-1)^2(z-3)}dz 
& = & -\frac 14 \oint_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{z - 1}dz-\frac 12 \oint_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{(z - 1)^2}dz \\
& = & -\frac 14\cdot 2\pi i \cdot e^1 -\frac 12 \cdot 2\pi i \cdot e^1 \\
& = & -\frac 32 \pi i e
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(z)=e^z/(z-3)$ is analytic on the open disc $D=\{z:|z|<5/2\}$ which includes the circle $C=\{z:|z|=2\}$  which surrounds the point $z=1.$ So $$\int_C\frac {f(z)}{(z-1)^2}dz=2\pi i f''(1).$$

For $z\ne 3$ let $g(z)=e^z$ and $h(z)=1/(z-3).$ We have $f''(1)=g''(1)h(1)+2g'(1)h'(1)+g(1)h''(1)=e(\,h(1)+2h'(1)+h''(1)\,)$.... etc.

Comment: You got the formula incorrectly. It should be $f'(1)$. See my comment below the question.